# Exporting data to csv file after web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, csv

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc="
loc = "Newport+Beach,+CA"
page = 10
url = base_url + loc + '&start='+ str(page)
yelp_r = requests.get(url)
yelp_soup = BeautifulSoup(yelp_r.text, 'html.parser')
businesses = yelp_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'biz-listing-large'})
file_path = 'yelp-{loc}.txt'.format(loc=loc)

with open(file_path,"a") as textfile:
    businesses = yelp_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'biz-listing-large'})
    for biz in businesses:
        title = biz.findAll('a',{'class':'biz-name'})[0].text
        print(title)
        address = biz.findAll('address')[0].text
        print(address)
        phone= biz.findAll('span',{'class':'biz-phone'})[0].text
        print(phone)
        page_line="{title}\n{address}\{phone}".format(
            title=title,
            address=address,
            phone=phone
        )
       textfile.write(page_line)
```

How to export the data to csv file, now it gets exported to txt file. I tried with csv.writer but it didnt work

Comment: I tried with with open("data.csv", "w+") as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
  writer.writerow(["SrNo", "Name"])
  writer.writerow(["Data 1", "Data 2"])

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with Python, but this is basically how I would do it if I was you.

```
import urllib2

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

urls = []

for company in listOfStocks:
    urls.append('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + company + '&d=6&e=28&f=2015&g=m&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv')

# Create a CSV on your desktop to hold that data that id scraped from the web . . .
Output_File = open('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Historical_Prices.csv','w')

New_Format_Data = ''

for counter in range(0, len(urls)):

    Original_Data = urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).read()

    if counter == 0:
        New_Format_Data = "Company," + urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).readline()

    rows = Original_Data.splitlines(1)

    for row in range(1, len(rows)):

        New_Format_Data = New_Format_Data + listOfStocks[counter] + ',' + rows[row]

Output_File.write(New_Format_Data)
Output_File.close()
```